# Assigning CSS classes to exposed widgets in a view?

Tags: views, 6, theming

I have several exposed widgets in a view, they allow users to sort stories by date or by tag. However, I am trying to style the block and because each widget is only given a 'views-exposed-widget' class by default, I can't figure out a way to style each widget differently. Is there a simple way to give each widget a different css class or id? I need to set different widths to different divs, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Drupal – Theme the Exposed Filter in Views](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2011/07/25/drupal-theme-the-exposed-filter-in-views/). Basically make a custom views-exposed-form.tpl.php file at your theme level that is specific to each of the widgets you have setup. You can then adjust the markup in each of the template files to include a unique ID to allow styling specific to each widget.